# Cannot bind to the property IN VB.NET

Tags: binding, bind, vb.net-2010

I have a problem Unable to bind property.
or because i have something wrong with my code.Please solution.
I'm using visual studio 2010.

```
    Private Sub PopulateDataGridView()
        Try
            dt = New DataTable
            Dim query = "select ITM,ITC,QOH,PRS,PRSOBBRT,PRSOBNET,FILENAME1,FILENAME2,FILENAME3,FILENAME4,FILENAME5,FILENAME6 FROM IFG WHERE QOH > 0 AND SHI = @SHI"
            Using con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(cn)
                Using cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(query, con)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SHI", ComboBox1.SelectedValue)
                    Using adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
                        'Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
                        adapter.Fill(dt)
                        Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
ExPictureBox1.PrePath = Pathimage & "\"
            ExPictureBox2.PrePath = Pathimage & "\"
            ExPictureBox3.PrePath = Pathimage & "\"
            ExPictureBox4.PrePath = Pathimage & "\"
            ExPictureBox5.PrePath = Pathimage & "\"
            ExPictureBox6.PrePath = Pathimage & "\"

            ExPictureBox1.DataBindings.Add("FileName", dt, "FILENAME1") 
            ExPictureBox2.DataBindings.Add("FileName", dt, "FILENAME2")
            ExPictureBox3.DataBindings.Add("FileName", dt, "FILENAME3")
            ExPictureBox4.DataBindings.Add("FileName", dt, "FILENAME4")
            ExPictureBox5.DataBindings.Add("FileName", dt, "FILENAME5")
            ExPictureBox6.DataBindings.Add("FileName", dt, "FILENAME6")
Catch myerror As OleDbException
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " & myerror.Message)
        Finally
        End Try
    End Sub
```

[image: Cannot bind to the property]

[image: bindings in the collection]
thanks roy

Comment: @RezaAghaei , maybe you can help me?

Comment: The data binding is NOT going to convert the `string` path of the image to an `Image` object. You will need the “actual” `Image` in the `DataTable` to bind the `PictureBox` to it.

Comment: @JohnG , This causes two bindings in the collection to bind to the same property. You can see the update screenshot. How the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub PopulateDataGridView()
        Try
            dt = New DataTable
            Dim query = "select ITM,ITC,QOH,PRS,PRSOBBRT,PRSOBNET,FILENAME1,FILENAME2,FILENAME3,FILENAME4,FILENAME5,FILENAME6 FROM IFG WHERE QOH > 0"
            Using con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(cn)
                Using cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(query, con)
                    Using adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
                        adapter.Fill(dt)
                        Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
ExPictureBox1.PrePath = Pathimage & "\"
            ExPictureBox2.PrePath = Pathimage & "\"
            ExPictureBox3.PrePath = Pathimage & "\"
            ExPictureBox4.PrePath = Pathimage & "\"
            ExPictureBox5.PrePath = Pathimage & "\"
            ExPictureBox6.PrePath = Pathimage & "\"

            ExPictureBox1.DataBindings.Add("FileName", dt, "FILENAME1") 
            ExPictureBox2.DataBindings.Add("FileName", dt, "FILENAME2")
            ExPictureBox3.DataBindings.Add("FileName", dt, "FILENAME3")
            ExPictureBox4.DataBindings.Add("FileName", dt, "FILENAME4")
            ExPictureBox5.DataBindings.Add("FileName", dt, "FILENAME5")
            ExPictureBox6.DataBindings.Add("FileName", dt, "FILENAME6")
Catch myerror As OleDbException
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " & myerror.Message)
        Finally
        End Try
    End Sub
```